# Php cannot read secure cookies

Tags: php, security, session, cookies

Php cannot read secure cookies.

Code(Javascript):

```
document.cookie = <?php echo '"'.$hCName.'="'; ?> + host + "; path=/; secure; HttpOnly";
document.cookie = <?php echo '"'.$uCName.'="'; ?> + username + "; path=/; secure; HttpOnly";
document.cookie = <?php echo '"'.$pCName.'="'; ?> + password + "; path=/; secure; HttpOnly";
document.cookie = <?php echo '"'.$dNCName.'="'; ?> + dbName + "; path=/; secure; HttpOnly";
document.cookie = <?php echo '"'.$dPCName.'="'; ?> + dbPort + "; path=/; secure; HttpOnly";
```

Code(Php):

```
<?php
include_once("../scripts/session_start.php");
$host = $_COOKIE[$_SESSION['hCName']];
$username = $_COOKIE[$_SESSION['uCName']];
$password = $_COOKIE[$_SESSION['pCName']];
$dbName = $_COOKIE[$_SESSION['dNCName']];
$dbPort = $_COOKIE[$_SESSION['dPCName']];
echo "Host: ".$host.", Username: ".$username.", Password: ".$password.", dbName: ".$dbName.", dbPort: ".$dbPort;
?>
```

**Edit:**
I am getting:

> Notice: Undefined index: hCName in C:\Users\joonas\Desktop\Webon cms\root\install\createTables.php on line 3
>
> Notice: Undefined index: in C:\Users\joonas\Desktop\Webon cms\root\install\createTables.php on line 3
>
> Notice: Undefined index: uCName in C:\Users\joonas\Desktop\Webon cms\root\install\createTables.php on line 4
>
> Notice: Undefined index: in C:\Users\joonas\Desktop\Webon cms\root\install\createTables.php on line 4
>
> Notice: Undefined index: pCName in C:\Users\joonas\Desktop\Webon cms\root\install\createTables.php on line 5
>
> Notice: Undefined index: in C:\Users\joonas\Desktop\Webon cms\root\install\createTables.php on line 5
>
> Notice: Undefined index: dNCName in C:\Users\joonas\Desktop\Webon cms\root\install\createTables.php on line 6
>
> Notice: Undefined index: in C:\Users\joonas\Desktop\Webon cms\root\install\createTables.php on line 6
>
> Notice: Undefined index: dPCName in C:\Users\joonas\Desktop\Webon cms\root\install\createTables.php on line 7
>
> Notice: Undefined index: in C:\Users\joonas\Desktop\Webon cms\root\install\createTables.php on line 7
> Host: , Username: , Password: , dbName: , dbPort:

Comment: What error are you getting? Explain "cannot read"

Comment: I don't think you can set httpOnly cookies from JS. :\

Comment: Undefined index errors means that your array isn't filled up properly check to see if that works first!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two points:

- As [Scott Arciszewski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2224584/scott-arciszewski) points out, HTTP Only cookies cannot be manipulated by JavaScript.
- Secure cookies are only available when the current protocol is HTTPS.